# What is the history of data compression tools on personal computers?

Tags: history, data-preservation, storage, utilities, compression

On UNIX, the progression of the most widespread data compression programs was as follows:

- (AFAIR: Pre System V) [compact](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/compact/) (suffix .C), dynamic [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)
- (AFAIR: introduced in System V) [pack](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/pack/) (suffix .z), static Huffman coding (could not work with streamed data)
- (AFAIR: appeared in a BSD distribution) [compress](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/compress/) (suffix .Z), [Lempel–Ziv–Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZW) algorithm
- (appeared everywhere) [gzip](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/gzip), [DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm from PKZIP
- ... and the rest is modern history

What is the story of data compression tools - with or without archiving capabilities - on personal computers, before [System Enhancement Associates and PKWARE, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_%28file_format%29#Lawsuits) programs appeared in 1985/1986?

Update: Ignoring as trivial those that were only capable of run-length encoding.

Comment: I think before ARC there was SQ and before that nothing, at least not in common use.

Comment: @RossRidge Thank you; that covers DOS and CP/M systems, what about others?

Comment: Is your questions more specifically "history of data compression __algorithms__"? Otherwise, with all the various self-extracting archive and executable formats on several platforms, the question might be too broad...

Comment: @BrianH Do you happen to know many data compression tools on personal computers **predating SEA and PKWARE**?

Comment: Ok. So you are saying the __timeframe__ is most important to your question... As in, tools and algorithms used on personal computers before about 1986?

Comment: Yes; effectively before data compression became the "mainstream". And ignoring run-length encoding (I've just updated the question) as not interesting.

Comment: There's a number of early MacOS compression programs that were largely *exotic*.

Comment: @tofro What was there before StuffIt?

Comment: The most 68k compression progs I know were based on StuffIt (ShrinkWrap, StuffIt Expander,...) and then there were .bin and .hqx (BinHex) files

Comment: There were LZW-based compression tools on the Commodore 64, referred to as 'crunchers', in 1985 and possibly before. Used for demos and cracked software but also packing level data. Things like the Expert Cartridge also had built-in program crunchers.

Comment: @AlanB what was their provenance?

Comment: @Leo B. I'm not sure what you mean but for example Chapter 9 of the Expert Cartridge manual: http://rr.c64.org/wiki/Expert_Cartridge_V3.1_Manual_Project64.txt

Comment: Most of the links are now 404, can you please update them?

Comment: @curiousdannii Please try archive.org and edit the question if you succeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story is told in this [1988 usenet post](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.sys.ibm.pc/UckorKDTYvk/r-f0C2G_WnAJ) by Paul Homchick:

> Some time went by and it was a CP/M world, and diskettes were bigger. 
>   In 1981 Richard Greenlaw released SQ and USQ, based on Huffman
>   encoding and written in BDS C.  This was the first popular compression
>   technique.  Greenlaw gave away the binaries and source code.
>   <...>
>   By 1983 it was getting hard to ignore the IBM PC as programs which
>   weren't written in BASIC started appearing.  SQ/USQ was ported by
>   Chuck Forsberg from unix C-source code.  LU was ported to the PC by
>   Tom Jennings, from a unix implementation named "lar" (for Library
>   ARchive).  Jennings and Forsberg gave these programs away.  <...> The
>   next advance came in 1985 when Thom Henderson of System Enhancements
>   Associates (SEA), released his ARC.EXE program.

Indeed, the CP/M [source code for SQ](http://www.classiccmp.org/cpmarchives/cpm/mirrors/oak.oakland.edu/pub/cpm/squsq/) is time-stamped 1983.

Comment: I was secretly hoping that a tool existed that used some kind of a "naive" non-LZ dictionary-based algorithm, akin to the one proposed in the 1978 book "Etudes for Programmers" by Charles Wetherell, but it looks that there were none.

Comment: That post omits one widely-used utility -- Crunch under CP/M was a standalone LZW compressor, using the same container format as SQ. http://www.classiccmp.org/cpmarchives/cpm/mirrors/oak.oakland.edu/pub/cpm/squsq/crunch.abs gives an overview .

Comment: @john_e Thank you, the contents of that directory are quite interesting.